# How to make divs float on both ends of another div?

Tags: html, css

I have tried this so far,

http://jsfiddle.net/BXSJe/4/

I am trying to place 2 divs in the left and right ends of another div, I tried using float:left and float:right but they are showing up in new Lines

I want something like this,

> [[leftcap]................. TITLE ............... [rightcap]]

I'm really sorry I can't represent better than this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="shell">
    <div id="title">
        <div id='leftcap'>o</div>
        TITLE HERE
        <div id='rightcap'>x</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #shell {
 width:500px;
 height:300px;
 background:lightGrey; 
}

#title {
 background:green;
 padding:5px;
 border-radius:25%;   
 text-align:center;
}
#content
{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:center;
}
#leftcap
{
    width:10%;
}
#rightcap
{
    width:10%;
}
#leftcap,#rightcap
{
    height:100%;
    width:10%;
    background:red;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Using float property solved the problem, I have another question, how to vertically center align the text in a container div ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is CSS's `float` property which kind of forces an element to be aligned either left or right.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BXSJe/820/

Hope this helped. :)

Comment: @cyberPheonix No problem, all the best with your `div`s! :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your HTML as such:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="floatLeft">Left floated text here</div>
    <div id="floatRight">Right floated text here</div>
</div>
```

and CSS as such:

```
div {
    background-color: Red;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#floatLeft {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color: Blue;
}

#floatRight {
    width:100px;
    float:right;
    background-color: Gray;
}
```

You can see this here->http://jsfiddle.net/g6U8n/

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your same code just need to add some properties, have a look at here

```
<div id="shell">
    <div id="title">
        <div id='leftcap'>o</div>
        TITLE HERE
        <div id='rightcap'>x</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#shell {
 width:500px;
 height:300px;
 background:lightGrey; 
}

#title {
 background:green;
 padding:5px;
 border-radius:25%;   
 text-align:center;
}
#content
{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:center;
}
#leftcap
{
    width:10%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#rightcap
{
    width:10%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
#leftcap,#rightcap
{
    height:100%;
    width:10%;
    background:red;
}
```

Hope this is work ;)